# How to create array of Filters in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I create Filter variable or Multiple filters in swift?
such as :

```
let i2 = $0.bCondition == "nonac"
let i3 = $0.aCondition == "nonac"
let i4 = $0.cCondition == "nonac"
if <some condition>{
  let i5 = $0.vCondition == "nonac"
  let i6 = $0.mCondition == "nonac"
 }
final filter = i2+i3+i4+i6+i5
```

This is what I'm looking for, is there any solutions are available? please guide me through a proper solution.

Comment: `aCondition`, `bCondition`, etc. seem like quite a code smell. You could probably make those into a `Dictionary`, making filtering quite trivial

Comment: can you show me a code example?

Comment: Not really, because I don't know enough about the nature of the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: I want to add multiple filters but dynamically. This is the problem.

Comment: That doesn't tell me much about the `aCondition` and other fields, what they do, and whether or not they can be reworked into a dictionary

Answer (score 3):

From the way it looks you want not simply dynamically *add* filters but also dynamically *evaluate* them.  For this purpose you could use closures and some operators declared to operate on them:

```
// Closure that takes no arguments and returns Bool
typealias Filter = () -> Bool

// Convenience operator to combine outputs of two filters with AND operator
func && (lhs: Filter, rhs: Filter) -> Filter {
    return {
        lhs() && rhs()
    }
}

// Convenience operator to combine outputs of two filters with OR operator
func || (lhs: Filter, rhs: Filter) -> Filter {
    return {
        lhs() || rhs()
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
var foo = "Foo"
let bar = "Bar"
let qux = "Qux"

let filter1: Filter = { foo == "Foo" }
let filter2: Filter = { bar == "Bar" }
let filter3: Filter = { qux == "Qux" }
let compositeFilter = filter1 && filter2 && filter3
//                  ^-- Is this what you are looking for?

let before = compositeFilter()

foo = "FOO"

let after = compositeFilter()

print(before)   // true
print(after)    // false
```

Comment: This is the way I'm looking for, A composite dynamic filter

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to convert your `aCondition`, `bCondition`, etc. fields into a `Dictionary`. From there, you can get the `keys` from your dictionary, and do some simple set arithmetic:

```
struct Struct {
    let dict : [String : String]
}

let struct1 = Struct(dict: [
    "aCondition" : "a",
    "bCondition" : "b",
    "cCondition" : "c"
])

let struct2 = Struct(dict: [
    "aCondition" : "a",
    "bCondition" : "b",
    "cCondition" : "nonac"
])

let structs = [struct1, struct2] //structs to be filtered

let filters : Set = ["cCondition"] //the keys to be checked for "nonac"

let filtered = structs.filter{ //filter all structs
    let dict = $0.dict //get the dict of keys from the current iteration
    let keys = Set(dict.keys) //make a set from the dict keys
    let keysToCheck = keys.intersection(filters) //filter out to get the keys we want

    let values = keysToCheck.map{dict[$0]} //get the values for the keys to check

    return values.contains{$0 != "nonac"} //only keep if value != "nonac"
}

print(filtered)print(output)
```